# react: This expression is not callable. Type 'never' has no call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am getting an error with `useStyles`. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? Typescript?

The error is this line:

```
const classes = useStyles();

import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
const drawerWidth = 240;
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  page: {
    background: "#f1f1f1",
    width: "100%",
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  root: {
    display: "flex",
  },
});

const Layout: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.page}>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Version information:

```
@material-ui/core@5.0.0-beta.5
│ ├─┬ @material-ui/system@5.0.0-beta.5
│ │ ├─┬ @material-ui/private-theming@5.0.0-beta.5
│ │ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ │ ├─┬ @material-ui/styled-engine@5.0.0-beta.5
│ │ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ @material-ui/unstyled@5.0.0-alpha.44
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ @material-ui/utils@5.0.0-beta.5
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-transition-group@4.4.2
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ @material-ui/icons@4.11.2
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ @mui/icons-material@5.2.4
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ @mui/material@5.2.4
│ ├─┬ @mui/base@5.0.0-alpha.60
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ @mui/system@5.2.4
│ │ ├─┬ @mui/styled-engine@5.2.4
│ │ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ @mui/utils@5.2.3
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ @mui/styles@5.2.3
│ ├─┬ @mui/private-theming@5.2.3
```

Comment: Which version of `material-ui` are you using?

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68887740/7011860

Comment: I added my version in original post

Comment: hi @zimmerbimmer, I checked your link.  how does that relate to my example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version is highly unstable (v5 beta). `@material-ui` has been renamed to `@mui` and v5 is now out of beta and at version 5.2.4 (at time of writing).

Uninstall `@material-ui`, run `npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled` and you should be good to go. I just tried the code below and no typescript errors.

See also [sample 3](https://mui.com/styles/api/#examples-3) for an example.

```js
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import type { FC } from "react";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  page: {
    background: "#f1f1f1",
    width: "100%",
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  root: {
    display: "flex",
  },
});


const Layout: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.page}>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Add `export default Layout`

Comment: got it, thank you!

Comment: can you tell me why I do const Layout... instead of export default function? (sorry for all questions)

Comment: Either will do. One is an arrow function notation (ES6+) the other is the older function notation.

Comment: which one is the arrow function?

Comment: This is the general form of arrow function `() => {}`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#comparing_traditional_functions_to_arrow_functions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240314/discussion-between-solarissf-and-sam-a).